# Merging 2 arrays to get unique values in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Got 2 df columns which I would like to merge together. Since most of the values are equal across corresponding rows I would like to create a single column with the unique value from each row.

What's the best way to achieve the below output?

Sample:

```
list1 = ['','','dog','cat','cat']
list2 = ['dog','','dog','cat','']
```

Output:

```
combined_list = ['dog','','dog','cat','cat']
```

Comment: What if two strings in the same "row" are different?

Comment: if 2 strings are different I would like to keep both strings together (comma separated) e.g combined_list = ['dog','','dog,cat','cat','cat']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `next` + `filter`:

```
list1 = ['','','dog','cat','cat']
list2 = ['dog','','dog','cat','']

L = [next(iter(filter(None, values)), '') for values in zip(list1, list2)]

['dog', '', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat']
```

Note this solution gives priority to the *first* "Truthy" value. It is extendable to an arbitrary number of input lists.

Comment: That works great for when I have the same string in the same row. For instances where I have 2 different strings I would like to add both unique string together e.g. ['dog', '', 'dog,cat', 'cat', 'cat']. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Something like `[','.join(filter(None, values)) for values in zip(list1, list2)]`.

Answer (score 4):

We can here use the `or` operator:

```
[x or y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Given the first item has truthiness `False` (this is the case for empty strings), it takes the second element. In case the first element has truthiness `True`, it takes the first element.

For the given sample input, we get:

```
>>> [x or y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
['dog', '', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat']
```

In case both elements have non-empty strings, it will thus take the first string.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order within each list important? Otherwise combine lists of sets of the lists:

```
combined_list = list(set(list1))+list(set(list2))
```